# WinForms Doughnut and Pie chart labels background element color property

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, properties, pie-chart

I'm using Doughnut and Pie Charts in WinForms C# desktop application

I change the color for section this way:

```
chart1.Series[0].Points[i1].Color = Color.Yellow;
```

as well as for `BackColor` and `BorderlineColor` from properties, but I can't find in `Series (Collection) Editor` property to change white background behind listed values (on right side on image, pointed with red arrow):

[image]

I've tried listed color properties, but none of them seems to affect this element:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thing is called a [legend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chart#Features_of_a_chart). You can reach it using [`Chart.Legends`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.legends?view=netframework-4.8) property and set its [`BackColor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.legend.backcolor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_DataVisualization_Charting_Legend_BackColor):

```
//by index
chart1.Legends[0].BackColor = Color.Black;
//by name through series object
chart1.Legends[chart1.Series[0].Legend].BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Hello, exactly. Thank you for links, I've missed it